# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (Angular 6)

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, express

I am trying to display MySQL tables in my project which is now fetching the tables from local json file.

```html
public getProperties(): Observable<Property[]>{
    return this.http.get<Property[]>(this.url + 'properties.json');

  }
```

When replacing the url with the one with which i'm fetching the mysql table object using NodeJs and express, I get the given error in console. This is how I went:

```
public getProperties(): Observable<Property[]>{
    return this.http.get<Property[]>('http://localhost:3000/');

  }
```

Is there a way I can successfully pass the url to access MySQL tables?

Here is my NodeJS code:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");

  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  console.log("Function called")
  con.query('SELECT * FROM authors', (err,rows) => {
    if(err) throw err;

    console.log('Data received from Db:');
    console.log(rows);
    DBRows = rows;

    console.log("Data sent")
    res.send(JSON.stringify(DBRows));
  });
});

  con.query('SELECT * FROM authors', (err,rows) => {
    if(err) throw err;

    console.log('Data received from Db:');
    console.log(rows);
    DBRows = rows;

    console.log("Data sent")
    JSON.stringify(DBRows);
    res.send(JSON.stringify(DBRows));

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the result of "JSON.stringify(DBRows)" ?

You are expecting an array of Property in the result (Property[]) but you return a stringified DBRows which is probably an object

You need to modify your code so the result match what you expect.
If the result of "JSON.stringify(DBRows)" is

```
{
   values: [ {/* DbRow */}, {/* DbRow */}, ... ]
}
```

Then in your service you need to expect a similar object, example :

```
export class Response {
   values: Property[];
}
...
return this.http.get<Response>('http://localhost:3000/');
```